# How to extend modules in lib directory of a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a module in `vendor/engine_name/lib/qa/qa.rb` and want to extend that module to include a class, `Foo`, in a separate file `vendor/engine_name/lib/qa/foo.rb`, so that `foo.rb` would look like this

```
module QA
  class Foo
    # code here
  end
end
```

When I try to create an instance of Foo in `qa.rb`, I get a `NameError`

I've tried loading `foo.rb` with loads of different filepaths but none of them work. What do I need to do to extend the module properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

qa.rb:

```
require "./foo"

module QA
  class Dog
  end
end

QA::Foo.new
```

However, the path `./foo` is relative to the directory that you run the program from, which may not be the `qa/` directory.

This is better:

qa.rb:

```
require_relative "./foo"

module QA
  class Dog
  end
end

QA::Foo.new
```

require_relative looks for the path `relative to the file` containing the require_relative statement.

If you write `require 'foo'`--without a path--then ruby only searches in certain predefined directories for foo.rb, which you can examine by looking at the output of:

```
require "pp"
pp $LOAD_PATH

--output:--

["/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0",
 "/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14"]
```

You can always add a directory to that array, e.g

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift '/path/to/your/ruby/file/'  #add to front of array
require 'your_ruby_file_name'
```